# Getting List elements

Tags: java, list

i have an ArrayList with elements for example:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h];
```

and need to take elements `[a,b,c]` also it should be an ArrayList and remove them from first List and again i take some elements from first list after i take i remove them.

So what is the best way (considering a time) to do this job ?
I mean i should iterate over elements or should convert to array and than work with it ?

maybe there are some fast way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to try and clarify what you mean here. 

You mean you are going to be constantly splitting a List (or other data structure) into separate groups and you want the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new list using [`subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) to get a view into the first, then use [`clear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear%28%29) on the subList.  Example:

```
subList = originalList.subList(0, 3);
newList = new ArrayList(subList);
subList.clear();
```

This is much more efficient than iterating over the original list removing one element at a time since removing an element from an ArrayList involves shifting all the elements.  Using a `subList` does the shift just once.

Comment: You can simplify this by doing `originalList.removeRange(0,3);`.

Comment: .. or use the same subList twice.

Comment: It write removeRange(int,int) has protected access in java.util.ArrayList, So i need to override this method ?

Comment: Ok, the `removeRange` solution won't work since that's not public.  Reverting back to `subList()` and `clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`sublist`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) method to split this list into two (making two calls to `sublist`).